# How do I show progress of copying files older than 1 day from one folder to other another?

Tags: powershell

We need to know in code what files were copied and some files were old and were not copied.

````
$date = (get-date).AddDays(-1)
get-childitem -File c:\t\*.*,c:\f\*.*,c:\u\*.*,c:\s\*.* | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date} | 
 Copy-Item  -Destination c:\t\1 ```
````

Comment: If you use `-Verbose` at the end of your `Copy-Item` it will display on the console window what files are being copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on PowerShell 4.0 or newer, you could use the `.Where({})` extension method in "Split" mode to split new and old files into two groups:

```
$new,$old = @(Get-ChildItem -File C:\t\*.*).Where({$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date}, 'Split')

# Write file names to log files
$new.Name > newfiles.txt
$old.Name > oldfiles.txt

$new | Copy-Item -Destination C:\t\1\
```

Comment: progress of copy we need only on screen

Answer (score 0):

If by 'showing progress' you mean writing some info to the console, then this could be what you want.

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$dest = 'C:\t\1'

# if the destination folder does not exist, create it first
if (!(Test-Path $dest -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $dest -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\t','C:\f','C:\u','C:\s' -File | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.LastWriteTime -gt $date) {
        Write-Host "Copying file '$($_.FullName)'" -ForegroundColor Green
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $dest
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "File '$($_.FullName)' is too old.. Skipped" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
}
```

Comment: how to rewrite code with many folders get-childitem -File c:\t\*.*,c:\f\*.*,c:\u\*.*,c:\s\*.*

Comment: @daver If you look at the `-Path` parameter in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6#parameters), you'll find it can take an array of paths. Also note that the Position for the `-Path` parameter is 0, so better put your path(s) first or use it Named like I did.

Comment: @daver P.S. What exactly are the folders named? When appending `*.*` to the name, the folders need to be called something like `C:\t_whatever.something-or-nothing`. I guess by adding `*.*` you actually mean to find any file in there regardless of the name, right? In that case, drop the `*.*` from the folder names. By not setting a filter for the filenames the `Get-ChildItem` function will return all.

Comment: @daver I just edited my answer to use the specified folders